# Scons PreAction Command is printed but apparently not executed

Tags: scons

I'm building  a large project with SCONS, for reasons out of this topic (large story)  I need to pass the object files options in the final linkage command inside a file.
Eg:

gcc -o program.elf @objects_file.txt -T linker_file.ld

This command works since I've tested it manually. But now I need to run it embedded in the Project build files. My first approach/idea has been to collect all the options into a file in the following way:

```
dbg_exe     = own_env.Program('../' + target_path, components)
own_env.AddPreAction(dbg_exe, 'echo \'$SOURCES\' > objects_file.txt')
```

note: the $sources contains all the object files I need.
As I expected the command seems to be executed , I see the command printed in the terminal but for some reason it has not been executed since I don't find the objects_file.txt anywhere.

It's curious that if I copy & paste the printed lines in the same terminal the command execution is successful so I suppose the syntax constructed is correct.

I tried also a shorter test code:

```
own_env.AddPreAction(dbg_exe, 'ls -l > salida_ls.txt')
```

... and another surprise , this time I get  syntax error in the console:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
ls -l > salida_ls.txt
ls: cannot access '>': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'salida_ls.txt': No such file or directory
```

a simple 'ls -l' works fine.

Any idea why this kind of bash commands don't work as expected? Is the *>* redirection symbol affecting the SCONS?

Some maybe useful information:

> OS Windows10
>
> Terminal mingw32
>
> SCons v2.3.1

After searching I've found out that this is something related with the redefinition of the SPAWN construction variable:

```
def w32api_spawn(sh, escape, cmd, args, e_env):
    
    print "CMD value" 
    print sh 
    print escape 
    print cmd
    print args
    print e_env
    print " ********************************** " 
    if cmd == "SHELL":
        return SCons.Platform.win32.spawn(sh,escape,args[1], args[1:],e_env)
    cmdline = cmd + ' ' + string.join(args[1:], ' ')
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= _subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmdline, 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, 
        startupinfo=startupinfo, 
        shell = False, 
        env = None
        )

    data, err = proc.communicate()
    
    print data
    rv = proc.wait()
    if rv:
        print "====="
        print err
        print "====="
    return rv
```

Comment: Please try with the current release of SCons 3.1.1

Comment: @bdbaddog , same error got!

Comment: Create a small example single file which reproduces the problem and post?

Comment: Actually, I've just seen that this is something related with the redefinition of the SPAWN contruction variable. We've inherited a building architecture from a 3rd party code and they are redefining the way the command line is called. If a run a simpler SContruct file this works. I've completed the information in the initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround running a python native function to build th efile I needed. Unfortunately I cannot afford more time with this issue, I didn't find the real reason and solution but it is clear is not something related with the normal SCONS performing but with the trick  performed in the SPAWN.

scons_common.GenerateObjectsFile('../' + objects_file, components)

Comment: That's not vanilla SCons.. it must be from the package you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'll need to swap back to the default SPAWN for that Program().

Add this to the top of that SConscript

```
from SCons.Platform.win32 import spawn
```

Then replace the logic you pasted above with:

```
dbg_exe     = own_env.Program('../' + target_path, components, SPAWN=spawn)
own_env.AddPreAction(dbg_exe, 'echo \'$SOURCES\' > objects_file.txt')
```

This assumes that you're only building on win32.  If that's not true you'll need to conditionally add the SPAWN to your Program() above only when you're on win32.

Comment: Now I get a different error: "ls" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo. In English means that ls is not recognise as a command. Is it trying to run a bash command in a cmd terminal? Anyway I found a workaround to deal with the problem. See below the answer

Comment: Yup. You must be.. :(